How select object from Redis cache by field value
I have spring data jpa project where some information is stored in Redis cache.
My entity for redis:
@RedisHash("UserViewEntity")
data class UserViewEntity(
    @Id
    val id: UUID,
    @Indexed
    val userId: String,
    val chatIdToCount: Map<UUID, Int>
)

If I need data for some user I use such repository method:
interface UserViewRepository : CrudRepository<UserViewEntity, UUID> {
    fun findByUserId(userId: String): UserViewEntity?
}

But I'm wondering how I can create a similar request in the radish cache itself. This doesn't look so trivial to me since I need to search by userId and not just by id.
For PostgreSQL it would look like:
SELECT * FROM _table where userId = '123';

But what should this look like for Redis?
